# Как найти индекс конкретного числа в списке? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

К примеру у нас есть список x = [1, 4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8], как найти индекс числа 7?

Comment: а если, к примеру, у вас в списке не одно число 7?

Answer (score 2):

Если вас интересует именно `list`, вам нужна функция `index`:

```
print([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].index(7))
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужных чисел в списке несколько, можно их индексы найти так:

```
x = [1, 4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 8, 7, 9]
indexes = [i for i,d in enumerate(x) if d == 7]
print(indexes)
```

```
[5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что решения с методом `index` вам поможет решить задачу, но хотелось бы подметить несколько важных моментов. Метод `index` работает за `O(n)`. Что не самый плохой результат, но всё же не идеальный. Для более эффективного поиска элемента в списке можно применить, так называемый "бинарный поиск".

[Wiki](https://www.google.com/search?q=binary%20search%20&newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALiCzsbz_Tv1ieWVDYi_2VXV9nA43YAqmQ%3A1670446906143&ei=Ov-QY_GcCJCKrwTU05RY&ved=0ahUKEwjxodPTs-j7AhUQxYsKHdQpBQsQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=binary%20search%20&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyCggAEIAEEIcCEBQyBQgAEIAEMgQIABBDMgoIABCABBCHAhAUMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6BAgjECc6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARCvAToOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQrwE6CAgAEIAEELEDOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOhAILhCxAxCDARDHARCvARBDOgcIABCxAxBDOggIABCxAxCDAUoECEEYAEoECEYYAFCIDFjiHWDBH2gDcAF4AIABaYgB9QWSAQM4LjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)

Его худшая асимптотика - `O(log n)`, что намного лучше, чем у `index`. Но для корректной работы бинарного поиска необходимо, чтобы список был отсортирован. Т.е. если в вашей задаче дан заведомо отсортированный список, то стоит обратить внимание на бинарный поиск.

В python есть стандартная библиотека, реализующая бинарный поиск - `bisect`.

[Доки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)